# effect of traditional ajax calls for my website

Tags: jquery, asp.net, websocket, push-notification, long-polling

I am building website its homepage has two grids that I want to update say 1 minutes or above.. I have used the traditional ajax calls to update the grid after one minute.. Now I have become aware of long polling and websockets.. the question is that should I leave the old way or change it to push technology?? Will the growth of users effect the system if yes then what is expected frequency after which the system will respond in unbehaved way? any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: It's going to be a hassle to support all mechanisms for all browsers. Since you're on ASP.NET have you looked at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)? That should do this all transparently for you, using whatever mechanism your end users' browsers support best.

Comment: yes I heard about this.. but not sure of microsoft because they keep experimenting and then drop it.. Like asp.net-ajax that did not work will though I wasted huge amount of time on it.. so I can't make my mind as to whether I sould consider it???

Comment: It's open-source on GitHub so it can survive Microsoft dropping it. But if you have a workable AJAX-only website then you might as well stick with that unless you're need shorter user updates or unless it's starting to overload your server.

Answer (score 1):

It mostly depends on the type of data you want to display in the grid. For a news feed or something similar, I would use AJAX calls. However, for live data such as comments, chat or a live commentary I would use websockets.

The growth of users will influence the performance of the application depending on how many users your website can facilitate. One host is able to deal with about a 1000 people at the same time, while others can only handle a few dozen. When too many users send and receive data to the server where your website is hosted, then both AJAX and websocket communication may slow down to the point of data never arriving.

Also, keep in mind that although AJAX is great for many solutions, websockets are meant for user experiences whereby the user stays for an extended period of time on a website.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes the users are expected to stay for long Its social networking website.. chat is not yet designed.. So I am thinking about that too.. Though I feel and am planning that the website will be able to attract students in huge number..